# Exporting Ad Hoc profile?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I'm developing an app with a friend. I have created an ad hoc profile from my dev account. What do I need to supply to him so he can build the app on his machine as well? Do I need to supply him the .cer or the .p12 and in the case of the latter do I need to give him the password for my p12 (really dont want to do this)

Comment: You could send the app to his iPhone using TestFlight so he would not need to build it.

Comment: If you just want him to be able to build the app and deploy to a device, he just needs the source code and a developer certificate. If you want him to be able to download the app to test it, then Alex's suggestion is the right one: Add his device ID to your provisioning profile and use a service like TestFlight or HockeyApp to distribute it over the air. If you want to share your developer certificate with him, then export the developer profile from Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your friend has Developer account then u must prefer Fonix suggestion..

If your friend hasn't Developer account then u have to collect the device id of your friend. Then add a device in your developer account with your friend's device id. After that, create a adhoc profile and archive your project. From the organizer in Xcode 4.6.1 you could distribute your app by binding the adhoc profile as ipa format. You just send the adhoc profile and the ipa file of your project to your friend. Tell your friend to connect the device and drag both of the file on iTunes logo, then iTunes will show your project in app tab..... after that just press install then your friend could experience your project...

Answer (score 0):

You dont need an ad hoc profile for that, that is purely for giving someone the app without having to upload it to the app store. he will just need to have his developer account added to your team, then he will need to upload his certificate to the team, and then add his certificate and his device to the development provisioning profile for the app

so in summary:

1. add your friend to your developer team
2. click on certificates and create a new developer certificate for your friend
3. (optional, probably already done this) create your app id (can be a wild card one for development, but easier if you just do this properly from the begining)
4. (optional, can just use the simulator) add you and your friends devices udids
5. create or edit your current development provisioning profile to include you and your friends certificates and devices, download this and double click to add to xcode automatically

and that should sort you out